# Is there a Box SDK for Mac OS X or must I use the REST API directly?

Tags: objective-c, macos, api, sdk, box-api

I'm adding support for Box to a suite of apps that spans iOS and OSX.  I picked up the Box Framework, which made the iOS side easy.  But that framework does not seem to support Mac.  Is there a Mac version?  Will there be soon?  Is there any alternative?  Or must I code directly to the REST API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't currently have an SDK for OS X, unfortunately. We may build one in the future, but for now you should make the REST API calls directly.

Comment: Yes! We ended up using that as a starting point and were able to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

I have OS X base box.com cocoa interface using REST interface.

Just simple file and folder operations and login in (networking is only sync interface for now). I have not release it to public yet, still look at making it Async and improving it..

Also for debugging REST API on Mac look at: http://code.google.com/p/cocoa-rest-client/